# Quotient of Vector Space of Continuous Functions

Tags: vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

Let $C^0(\Omega)$ and $C^1(\Omega)$ be the vector spaces of continuous and continuously differentiable functions on a closed subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}$ . What is known about the (linear-algebraic) quotient space $C^0(\Omega)/C^1(\Omega)$? Is it isomorphic to any well-known vector spaces?

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say its dimension is still $2^{\aleph_0}$. Since you are quotienting by a non-closed (actually, a dense) subspace, the quotient topology is not metrisable.

Comment: It actually has dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$: assuming $\Omega$ is an interval (or something of sort), consider, for any point $c$, a differentiable function $g_x$ the derivative of which is discontinuous exactly in $c$. Then, $\{g_x\,:\,x\in\Omega\}$ is a family of linearly independent functions the span of which intersects $C^1(\Omega)$ trivially. Its cardinality is obviously $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: A closed subset of $\mathbb R$? What is $C^1$ of the Cantor set?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli So metrisability is lost, understood. But can such a pathological quotient space still be locally convex (requiring an uncountable number of seminorms)?